# Hive function to get epoch milliseconds or convert epoch milliseconds to date without converting milliseconds to seconds

Tags: sql, hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to get date in epoch milliseconds or vice versa in HIVE?
There are function like "unix_timestamp()" and "from_unixtime()" but they work with seconds.

P.S : My use case restricts me to convert seconds to milliseconds (seconds*1000 =millis)

Background -> I want to write query which should run in hive and snowflake without changing syntax but the datatype for column in HIVE is BIGINT and data type in Snowflake is TIMESTAMP.
And in query which works in hive:
unix_timestamp('20220714','yyyyMMdd')*1000 > SomeColumn

I have created function in snowflake for unix_timestamp as below which works same as hive function i.e. it converts given string to epoch seconds:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_INPUT String, FORMAT STRING)
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  DATE_PART(EPOCH_SECOND,TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_INPUT,FORMAT))
$$;
```

But the issue in snowflake is left side value of "<" operator is integer whereas right side column is TIMESTAMP which causes error in snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to create a function on both HIVE and Snowflake:

```
CREATE FUNCTION unix_timestamp_ms(date_input STRING, format STRING)
 RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
 RETURN unix_timestamp(date_input,format)*1000
END;
```

Please note that I can't check the above function, I just assume it will work based on HPL/SQL docs. http://www.hplsql.org/about

So after you create that function, your query will be like:

```
WHERE unix_timestamp_ms('20220714','yyyyMMdd') > SomeColumn
```

And in Snowflake, you will create the function like this (no need to convert to epoch):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unix_timestamp_ms(DATE_INPUT String, FORMAT STRING)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_INPUT,FORMAT)
$$;
```

So you will be able to use the same query for HIVE and Snowflake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but don't want to create function in hive. 
I used to_utc_timestamp() function to achieve this :

to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp(A_CA.MoveDate,'yyyyMMdd')*1000,'UTC') > to_utc_timestamp(somecolumn,'UTC')

And created UDF in snowflake for this method.

Comment: @Sella In this case, you need to use the same data type. You said "HIVE is BIGINT and data type in Snowflake is TIMESTAMP" - re-define the column as NUMBER in Snowflake.

Comment: In hive to_utc_timestamp function converts BIGINT to TIMESTAMP on both side of ">" operator, in snowflake I created same "to_utc_timestamp" functions with different input types and this works for my case.